# Proving equality, Leibniz' theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, binomial-coefficients

This is a tiny part from a bigger problem, and  I redid it a couple of times but I just cant get to it.
So we have the equality $$(1-x^2)f''(x)-xf'(x)-2=0$$ and using Leibniz' binomial theorem on $$(1-x^2)f''(x)$$ and $$xf'(x)$$ we need to reach the general form $$(1-x^2)f^{n+1}(x)-(2n-1)xf^n(x)-(n-1)^2f^{n-1}(x)=0$$

I get the right coefficients for the first two terms, but the third one its way off the textbook solution. Anyone ele could try?

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-x^2)f''-xf'-2=0$$
Differentiating $n$ times w.r.t.x, we get
$$(1-x^2)f^{n+2}-2nx f^{n+1}-2\frac{n(n-1)}{2} f^n-x f^{n+1}-nf^{n}$$
$$\implies (1-x^2) f^{n+2}-(2n+1)xf^{n+1}-n^2f^n=0$$